# Убрать в ListBox-е перемещение клавишами вниз вверх

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Здраствуйте, есть необходимость убрать в листбоксе перемещение клавишами вниз/вверх, оставив только изменение выделенного элемента мышью. как такое сделать?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно подписаться на событие `PreviewKeyDown` и устанавливать `e.Handled = true`:

XAML:

`<ListBox PreviewKeyDown="lstTest_PreviewKeyDown"> 
  <ListBoxItem Content="test" /> 
  <ListBoxItem Content="test2" />
</ListBox>`

C#:

```
private void lstTest_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.Key)
    {
         case Key.Up:
         case Key.Down: 
              e.Handled = true; 
              break;
         default:
              break;
    }
}
```

Также можно просто установить свойство `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation` на `None`.
[<Источник>](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/wpf/thread/c7e0f5db-b58f-4bba-89f8-f8690356b92a)

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

Прописываем listbox-у следующий обработчик события:

```
PreviewKeyDown="listBox_PreviewKeyDown"
```

И в нем пишем следующее:

```
private void listBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Собственно, ваш вопрос на SO: [Disabling keyboard navigation in WPF ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639307/disabling-keyboard-navigation-in-wpf-listbox)

Comment: пока писал ответ, Вы уже опубликовали :)